# jQuery window scroll turn back on after off

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a script that changes the way my menu looks when you scroll past a certain point, to stop it repeating my animation over and over again I have put in a `$(window).off("scroll");` so it only executes once. I need the menu to change back again when I scroll back past the same point again, but once I have turned off scroll, is there a way I can turn it back on at certain point?

This is what I have so far:

```
    var Header = $('#header');
    var Navbar = $('.navbar');
    var links = $(".navbar ul.nav > li > a");
    var HeaderH = Header.height();
    var NavbarH = Navbar.height();


$(window).on("scroll", function(){      
    if ($(this).scrollTop() === (HeaderH + 64)) {
        $(window).off("scroll");
        Navbar.addClass('navbar-fixed-top')
        links.css('padding', '10px 20px 10px 20px');
        Header.css('margin-bottom', '64px');
        $('.navbar-fixed-top').css('top', '-64px')
        $('.navbar-fixed-top').animate({'top' : '0'}, 1000);    
    }
});
```

Comment: I have read your question, however $(window).off("scroll") - turning scroll of, is the bad approach, you should instead find a way to use a condition, function, or something.

Comment: is ($(this).scrollTop() === (HeaderH + 64)) by any chance true every time you scroll, after the animation fires at least once?

Comment: $('.navbar-fixed-top').css('top', '-64px') - why is there a negative value here?

Comment: the negative value is to hide the nav before animating to appear from the top. is this a badly worded question to get a down vote?

Comment: Not at all, I find it as a challenge, someone probably downvoted cause of bad code quality, but that has nothing to do with your question. I understand your question, I had to deal with similar stuff in the past.

Comment: ah i see. my code is always slightly scrappy during build, then when i get my desired outcome i go back and neaten everything up, i find it easier to read through whats going on when things are written out in full to start with. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just toggle a custom class :

```
var Header = $('#header');
var Navbar = $('.navbar');
var links = $(".navbar ul.nav > li > a");
var HeaderH = Header.height();
var NavbarH = Navbar.height();

$(window).on("scroll", function(){      
    if ($(this).scrollTop() >= (HeaderH + 64)) {
        if (!Navbar.hasClass('myclass')) {
            Navbar.addClass('navbar-fixed-top myclass')
            $('.navbar-fixed-top').stop().animate({'top' : '0'}, 1000);
        }
    } else {
        Navbar.removeClass('navbar-fixed-top myclass');
    }
});
```

And CSS :

```
.myclass {
    padding: 10px 20px;
    margin-bottom: 64px;
    top: -64px;
}
```